# Force browser of Sony PRS-T1 to download .epub files

Tags: php, apache, http, http-headers, download

The builtin browser of my ebook-reader (Sony PRS-T1) somehow doesn't like to download .epub files.

Normally it opens .epub files as if they were text-files.

With this php-download-script I managed to force the browser to download files I store on my server:

```
<?php

$path = $_GET['path'];
$mimeType = $_GET['mimeType'];

if(!file_exists($path)) {
    // File doesn't exist, output error
    die('file not found');
} else {
    $size = filesize($path);
    $file = basename($path);

    // Set headers
    header("Pragma: public"); // required
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers 
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"");
    header("Content-Type: $mimeType");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: $size");
    // Read the file from disk
    readfile($path);
}
exit();
?>
```

Now, the PRS-T1 would download the file but for some reason I don't understand it will change the file extension from .epub to .htm - this is weird.

But it seems like there is a way to do it right: when I download a .epub file from [readbeam.com](http://www.readbeam.com) it works just like expected (I found this hint at http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=163466).

What is it, that makes the difference betweeen their configuration and mine?

Here's what I found out using firebug:

http://tinypic.com/r/vzzkzp/5
[image: readbeam]

http://tinypic.com/r/2h7pbth/5
[image: mine]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Content-Type` header doesn't match the one from readbeam.

`application/epub zip` != `application/epub+zip`

The `+` is probably being seen by PHP as a space since it seems you are passing it via $_GET.

Comment: you are absolutely right! I now use `urlencode()` to solve it :)

Comment: For future readers, also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123809/force-download-only-displays-in-browser-doesnt-prompt-for-download#answer-22228190

Comment: @gibberish agar part of that other page should I be looking at?